# AWS - Read SQS Message via Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Below code is copied from AWS documentation, but my code is almost the same except for the queue URL definition part.

I want to print out the message body in JSON format, but it seems it has some things extra. How can I get rid of them without using substring?

```
# Create SQS client
# blah blah

# Receive message from SQS queue
response = sqs.receive_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    AttributeNames=[
        'SentTimestamp'
    ],
    MaxNumberOfMessages=1,
    MessageAttributeNames=[
        'All'
    ],
    VisibilityTimeout=0,
    WaitTimeSeconds=0
)

message = response['Messages'][0]
receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']

print('Received and deleted message: %s' % message)
```

This printed message has following format:

```
START RequestId: fe107bc8-3829-4600-9bfc-df89f59b0c70 Version: $LATEST
{JSON body}
END RequestId: fe107bc8-3829-4600-9bfc-df89f59b0c70
REPORT RequestId: fe107bc8-3829-4600-9bfc-df89f59b0c70  Duration: 914.38 ms Billed Duration: 1000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 71 MB  Init Duration: 247.03 ms
```

What I really want is just the {JSON body}. How can I get rid of the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **you can't remove**

```
START RequestId: fe107bc8-3829-4600-9bfc-df89f59b0c70 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: fe107bc8-3829-4600-9bfc-df89f59b0c70
REPORT RequestId: fe107bc8-3829-4600-9bfc-df89f59b0c70  Duration: 914.38 ms Billed Duration: 1000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 71 MB  Init Duration: 247.03 ms
```

from the CloudWatch Logs. This is standard print out behavior for a lambda function.

However, you can use [log event filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) in console which can help with locating specific `{JSON body}` of interest. It is the most basic and fastest to solution to use though.

More complex filtering of your logs is also possible, but I think this is not what you are after.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! By the way, I'm not explicitly using CloudWatch though. What I am trying to do here is: 1. Generate S3 event notification on PUT action, and publish the notification to SQS queue. 2. Trigger Lambda function periodically to read that SQS queue. By doing so, I want to ensure event is indeed generated (e.g. file is indeed uploaded on time). If not, Lambda will send email alert. Hence, I am not sure how CloudWatch log event filter will help me in this case?

Comment: @Henrix The log output from lambda does not stop you in doing any of these things. From your question its not clear what's the problem with the current lambda log structure. I assumed its difficult to search for your print outs?

Comment: I want to use Lambda to parse the {JSON body}, in order to identify the S3 event details contained in JSON body. Right now, the JSON body is surrounded by the strings that I mentioned above, which contains those START/END RequestId etc.. I find it difficult to get S3 event details out of this long string. If it were simple {JSON body}, I could have parsed it easily, like body['s3']['bucketname'].

Comment: @Henrix You can try `print(json.dumps(message, default=str))`. This can make json to be easier to read in the CW logs.

Comment: *"Right now, the JSON body is surrounded by the strings that I mentioned above, which contains those START/END RequestId etc."* @Hendrix no, it is not.  Your example output doesn't include the string `Received and deleted message` that your code indicates should be there so it does not appear that your code actually created this output.